# Does the number of zero eigenvalues correspond to the dimension of equilibrium manifold for nonlinear system?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Consider nonlinear dynamical system with $m \times m$ Jacobian matrix $J(x)$ that has $k$ zero eigenvalues for all $x$. The rest $m-k$ eigenvalues have negative real part for all $x$. Is that true that such dynamical system has $k$-dimensional locally attractive equilibrium  manifold? Any hints on literature in this direction will be very appreciated.

Is my question related to the Normally hyperbolicaly invariant manifolds?

Comment: It seems what you are looking for is the center manifold theorem. Google that term and you will find a bazillion references. The term "equilibrium manifold" seems ambiguous without proper definition.

Comment: I did look at center manifold theorem, but it just tells about the existance of a center manifold when at least one of the eigenvalues of the Jacobian is zero. My question is the number of zero eigenvalues correspond to the dimension of center manifold? Is center manifold is the same as what I call equilibrium manifold, i.e. if there is one zero eigenvalue equilirium set is a line, when two zero eigenvalues it is a plane and so on?

Comment: Keep reading, and you will find your questions answered.